# jqgrid jsonReader configuration

Tags: asp.net, jqgrid, webmethod, jsonreader

I'm new to jqgrid finally i've setup a grid.  Suppose i need to setup jsonReader so that the grid knows where to get my grid-data in the json return.  However i got blank cells after trying for days.

Here is my grid:

```
jQuery("#list48").jqGrid({
            url: 'dbtest.aspx/get_offsite_history2',
            datatype: "json",
            mtype: 'POST',
            ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },
            serializeGridData: function(postData) {
                return JSON.stringify(postData);
            },
            jsonReader: {
                root: function(obj) { alert(JSON.stringify(obj.d)); return obj.d; },
                repeatitems: false
            },
            height: 'auto',
            rowNum: 30,
            rowList: [10, 20, 30],
            colNames: ['name', 'start_date', 'duration', 'offsite_cat'],
            colModel: [
                          { name: 'name', index: 'name', width: 80, align: 'left', editable: true, edittype: 'text' },
                          { name: 'start_date', index: 'start_date', width: 120, align: 'left', editable: true, edittype: 'text' },
                          { name: 'duration', index: 'duration', width: 120, align: 'left', editable: true, edittype: 'text' },
                          { name: 'offsite_cat', index: 'offsite_cat', width: 120, align: 'left', editable: true, edittype: 'text'}],
            pager: "#plist48",
            viewrecords: true,
            sortname: 'name',
            caption: "Grouping Array Data",
            gridview: true
        });
```

This is the server return from url dbtest.aspx/get_offsite_history2:

```
{"d":"[{\"name\":\"A\",\"start_date\":\"B\",\"duration\":\"C\",\"offsite_cat\":\"D\"}]"}
```

i suppose to get the result by setting "root: 'd'" but i got 64 blank rows for that...

look for comments... many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason of your problem is the bug in your server code. You make serialization to JSON **twice**. After deserializing of `d` property of the server response you get still JSON string (!!!) instead of object. Typical error is manual usage of `JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize` in the web method. One should return the **object** itself instead of the string which is the result of serializing.

Without modifying of your current server code you can fix the problem by usage of

```js
jsonReader: {
    root: function (obj) {
        alert(typeof obj.d === "string" ? obj.d : JSON.stringify(obj.d));
        return typeof obj.d === "string" ? $.parseJSON(obj.d) : obj.d;
    },
    repeatitems: false,
    page: function () { return 1; },
    total: function () { return 1; },
    records: function (obj) {
        return typeof obj.d === "string" ? $.parseJSON(obj.d).length : obj.length;
    }
}
```

or (if you use `loadonce: true`) just

```
jsonReader: {
    root: function (obj) {
        return typeof obj.d === "string" ? $.parseJSON(obj.d) : obj.d;
    },
    repeatitems: false
}
```

Because your current server code seems not implemented the paging of data you should increase `rowNum` to some large enough value like `rowNum: 10000` or to use `loadonce: true`.

**UPDATED**: You can find [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/user2045340.htm) modified demo which works. It displays

[image]

after the `alert` message.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the structure of your returned json data.

Below is one that I use :

```
{   "page":1,
    "rows":[{"id":"1","cell":["1","1","Row 1","3","9",""]},
            {"id":"2","cell":["2","2","Row 2","2","1",""]},
            {"id":"3","cell":["3","4","Row 3","2","0",""]}],
    "records":3,
    "total":1
}
```

You may need to add a colModel for id to uniquely identify each row.

e.g.

```
      colNames: ['id', 'name', 'start_date', 'duration', 'offsite_cat'],
        colModel: [
                      { name: 'id', index: 'id', hidden: true },
                      { name: 'name', index: 'name', width: 80, align: 'left', editable: true, edittype: 'text' },
                      { name: 'start_date', index: 'start_date', width: 120, align: 'left', editable: true, edittype: 'text' },
                      { name: 'duration', index: 'duration', width: 120, align: 'left', editable: true, edittype: 'text' },
                      { name: 'offsite_cat', index: 'offsite_cat', width: 120, align: 'left', editable: true, edittype: 'text'}],
```

Hope that helps.