# How to bind a JsonResult object to jqgrid?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid, jsonresult, jsonreader

I have the following method in the controller which I call from my view to populate a jqgrid. This method works fine and returns data.

```
public JsonResult _FirstLook()
{
    HttpResponseMessage response;

    response = client.GetAsync("api/CasoAdverso").Result;
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            IEnumerable<CasoAdverso> list = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<CasoAdverso>>().Result;

            return Json(list);
        }
}
```

If I debug what is being returned the structure would be like the picture below. The list of objects is in Data:

[image]

I will summarize the CasoAdverso class because it's quite big for putting it here:

```
public class CasoAdverso
{
    public int CAAD_Id { get; set; }
    public string CAAD_Id_Local { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime? CAAD_Fecha_Contacto { get; set; }
}
```

The jqgrid actually receives data to populate but somehow is not being displayed:

```
$(grid_selector).jqGrid({
datatype: "json",
height: 250,
mType: 'GET',
url: "@Url.Action("_FirstLook", "CasoAdversoForm")", 
colNames: ['ID', 'ID Caso', 'Fecha Contacto Notif.'],
        colModel: [
            {   name: 'CAAD_Id', index: 'CAAD_Id', key: true },
            {   name: 'CAAD_ID_Local', index: 'CAAD_ID_Local', width: 60, editable: false },
            {  name: 'CAAD_Fecha_Contacto', index: 'CAAD_Fecha_Contacto', width: 90, editable: false, sorttype: "date", unformat: pickDate },
        ],
  ...
        },
```

I'm aware that the solution might come through the jsonReader in jqgrid but I couldn't make any progress without totally changing my _FirstLook method in the controller.

In my scenario I would need to change the jqgrid to bind what I'm currently getting from the controller. It would be good not having to do some workaround in the controller to give the jqgrid what he needs by default.

Comment: Please define "bind": what is the expect behavior? How does it differ from the actual behavior?

Comment: In this case the binding would be setting the jsonReader which will "link" the structure that the grid expects with the structure of the JsonResult object.
The expected behaviour would be populating and displaying but this is not happening...

Comment: There is an example of the jsonreader here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14748169/jqgrid-jsonreader-configuration

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that the main reason of the described problem isn't "binding". You use `mType: 'GET'` option which will be ignored because the option with the name `mType` is not exist. So the default option value `mtype: 'GET'` (`mtype` instead of `mtype`) will be used. So you should either use `mtype: 'POST'` or replace the line

```
return Json(list);
```

to

```
return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Additionally I would recommend you to verify that you use `loadonce: true` option because you don't implemented server side paging in your server code. I recommend you additionally to use `gridview: true`, `autoencode: true` options and consider to use `height: "auto"` instead of `height: 250`.