# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) When using JqGrid

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid

I am Getting Problem as Server returns 500 Error.
Same URL is running on When i use inside ajax call

URL is = "TestService.asmx/GetQueryInfo"

```
jQuery("#list2").jqGrid({
                        mtype: 'POST',
                        postData: "{ TableName: '" + TableName + "', ColumnList: '" + ColumnNames + "' }",
                        serializeGridData: function (postData) {
                            // extend the parameter which will be send to the server
                            postData = JSON.stringify(postData);
                            // serialize the parameters as JSON string
                            alert(postData);
                            return JSON.stringify(postData);
                        },
                        url: "PredictiveDialer.asmx/GetQueryInfo",
                        ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
                        datatype: 'json',
                        colNames: ['ID', 'Code', 'Name', 'PassWord', 'ClientLevel', 'DeptNo', 'DeptName'],
                        colModel: [
                            { name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 55 },
                            { name: 'code', index: 'code', width: 90 },
                            { name: 'name', index: 'name', width: 100 },
                            { name: 'password', index: 'password', width: 80, align: "right" },
                            { name: 'ClientLevel', index: 'ClientLevel', width: 80, align: "right" },
                            { name: 'DeptNo', index: 'DeptNo', width: 80, align: "right" },
                            { name: 'DeptName', index: 'DeptName', width: 150, sortable: false }
                        ],
                        rowNum: 10,
                        rowList: [10, 20, 30],
                        pager: '#pager2',
                        sortname: 'id',
                        viewrecords: true,
                        sortorder: "id",
                        caption: "JSON Example",
                        jsonReader: {
                            root: function (obj) { return obj.d; },
                            page: function () { return 1; },
                            total: function () { return 1; },
                            records: function (obj) { alert(obj.d.length); return obj.d.length; }
                        }                        
                    });
                    jQuery("#list2").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager2', { edit: false, add: false, del: false });
```

and WebService Code is as below

```
[WebMethod]    
public String GetQueryInfo(String TableName, String ColumnList)
{
    String daresult = String.Empty;
    String SQL = String.Empty;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("MyConnectionString");       
    SQL = "Select " + ColumnList + " From "+ TableName;
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(SQL, con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    sda.Fill(ds);
    daresult = DataSetToJSON(ds);
    return daresult;

}

public string DataSetToJSON(DataSet ds)
{
    Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
    {
        object[] arr = new object[dt.Rows.Count + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray;
        }
        dict.Add(dt.TableName, arr);
    }
    JavaScriptSerializer json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    return json.Serialize(dict);
}
```

Is Something wrong With Above Code?

**UPDATED CODE**

Now i used new function to paise columnname with ColumnValue inArray

Server Side :

```
[WebMethod]
public Object GetQueryInfo(String TableNames, String ColumnList)
{
    Object daresult = new Object();
    String SQL = String.Empty;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("MyConnection");
    SQL = "Select top 2 " + ColumnList + " From " + TableNames;
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(SQL, con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    sda.Fill(ds);
    daresult = DataTableToJSON(ds.Tables[0]);
    //daresult = DataSetToJSON(ds);
    return daresult;

}

public object DataTableToJSON(DataTable table)
{     
    List<Dictionary<string, object>> list = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
        {
            dict[col.ColumnName.ToLower()] = row[col];
        }
        list.Add(dict);
    }       
    return list;
}
```

Client Side :

```
jQuery("#list2").jqGrid({
                     mtype: 'POST',
                     url: "MyService.asmx/GetQueryInfo", 
                     serializeGridData: function (postData) {
                         return JSON.stringify({
                             TableNames: TableName,
                             ColumnList: ColumnNames
                         });
                     },

                     ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json; //charset=utf-8" }, //charset=utf-8                       
                     datatype: 'json',
                     colNames: ['ID', 'Code', 'Name', 'PassWord', 'ClientLevel', 'DeptNo', 'DeptName'],
                     colModel: [
                         { name: 'ID', index: "ID", width: 55, key: true, localreader: { id: "ID" } },
                         { name: 'Code', width: 90, align: 'left' },
                         { name: 'Name', width: 100, align: 'left' },
                         { name: 'PassWord', width: 80 },
                         { name: 'ClientLevel', width: 80 },
                         { name: 'DeptNo', width: 80 },
                         { name: 'DeptName', width: 150 }
                     ],
                     jsonReader: {
                         repeatitems: false,
                         root:'d',
                         page: function (obj) { return 1; },
                         total: function (obj) { return 1; },
                         records: function (obj) { return obj.length; },
                         id : "ID"
                     },

                     autoencode: true,
                     gridview: true,
                     rowNum: 10,
                     loadonce: true,
                     rowList: [10, 20, 30],
                     pager: '#pager2',
                     viewrecords: true,
                     caption: "JSON Example",

                     loadError: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                         alert('HTTP status code: ' + jqXHR.status + '\n' +
                               'textStatus: ' + textStatus + '\n' +
                               'errorThrown: ' + errorThrown);
                         alert('HTTP message body (jqXHR.responseText): ' + '\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
                     }

                 });
                 jQuery("#list2").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager2', { edit: false, add: false, del: false });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code have many problems. The main is: you convert the data returned from `GetQueryInfo` explicitly to JSON string which is wrong. The method should return `Object` instead of `String`. The .Net framework will convert the returned object to the JSON string automatically for you.

The second problem is the wrong usage of `postData`. You should never try to convert the returned object to JSON manually (like you do with `"{ TableName: '" + TableName + "', ColumnList: '" + ColumnNames + "' }"`). Instead of that you can just remove `postData` and modify the code of `serializeGridData` to something like

```js
serializeGridData: function () {
    return JSON.stringify({
        TableName: TableName,
        ColumnList: ColumnNames
    });
}
```

It will **replace** the standard parameters which will be send typically to the server to `TableName` and `ColumnList`.

You should never trust the input data in your server code. The current implementation of `GetQueryInfo` is ideal way for [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) (see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) for example too). Such code should be never used in production.

The last remark. You should add some options in jqGrid: `loadonce: true` (because you don't implemented server side paging of data), `gridview: true` (to improve the performance of the grid), `autoencode: true` (to interpret the input data as text and not as HTML fragments). I recommend you to add `loadError` cellback to the grid (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6969114/315935)). To display an error message in case of server side errors like 500.

Comment: Thanks For your reply Please look this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26770284/jqgrid-not-binding-data

Comment: @RamdasBhosale: You are welcome! I suppose you still don't change the code of `DataSetToJSON` like I suggested. I suppose that you still use `JavaScriptSerializer.JavaScriptSerializer` which is wrong. `GetQueryInfo` methow should return `Object` ainstead of `String`.

Comment: I have change return Datatype From String to object It returns Valid Json but Not Binding to JqGrid

Comment: @RamdasBhosale: You should append your question with updated code of web method. I still think that you use *old* code because the value of `d` property is the string. You can use `root` in `jsonReader` as function defined like in [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14749279/315935). In the case it will works in your case too. So you can use `jsonReader: {repeatitems: false, root: function (obj) { return typeof obj.d === "string" ? $.parseJSON(obj.d) : obj.d; }, records: function (obj) { return obj.length; }, page: function () { return 1; }, total: function () { return 1; }}`

Comment: u r Great this works me and data is displayed in Grid. Thats Man.